# stop background processing on reportviewer cancel

Tags: asp.net, .net, reportviewer, report-viewer2010, reportviewer2008

I have a web page where user can select report parameters and when submit the request im opening a popup window where report is being generated with the help of report viewer control.

when the report is still processing and user closes the popupwindow , then the background processing is still active, because of this when i click on any link in main parent page it is taking lot of time to load.when i checked it with fiddler i came to know that it is because of the reportserver requests that are been processing in the background are causing this issue.

I tried to kept a Close button on the popup page and on the server side close click event im trying to Reset the reportviewer, but even this is not stopping those requests that are running in the background.

below is the Reset code which didn't work

```
 Protected Sub btnClose_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnClose.Click

    rptViewer.Reset()

 End Sub
```

Is there a way to dispose these background processing of requests.